# How to click on a button inside list element of a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-listview, android-button

[image: Image of my RecyclerView activity]

So I have `recyclerview` here, and I want to ***delete a specific element*** by clicking on **that element's delete button** (here, the *trash icon* is the `image button`). How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the interface to do that.
Make a interface class like this:

```
interface OnItemClickListener {
     fun onDeleteIconClick(position)
}
```

Add listener object in the Recyclerview Adapter constructor

```
class RecyclerAdapter(
    val context: FragmentActivity,
    val listner: OnItemClickListener 
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
}
```

Then, on delete icon click add below code

```
listner.onDeleteIconClick(position)
```

then, on fragment or activity implement the interface and do whatever you want on the implemented method